# Google play console, как обновить приложение

Tags: unity3d, google-play-console

Как обновить приложение не перезаливая его полностью, а лишь нововведения? Не думаю что перекачивать каждое обновление по 40 мб это норма. unity

Comment: обычная `.apk` будет скачиваться полностью. Но вы можете использовать например `obb` файл, или подгружать контент со своего сервера и т.д. В юнити есть встроенный bundle assets для этого.

Comment: @pavel, идиотизм. перекачивать постоянно apk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почтитайте про Android App Bundle: https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вы можете не делать ничего - Google Play всё сделает за вас.
.apk файл - это просто архив. Когда вы загружаете новую сборку на google play - гугл её распаковывает и сверяет все файлы с теми, которые были в прошлой сборке. При обновлении приложения на телефоне до новой версии будут скачаны только те файлы, которые отличались.

Для небольших игр этого вполне достаточно. Если же в вашей игре много различных тяжёлых ресурсов, то они разбиваются на логические группы, которые пакуются в asset bundle и докачиваются уже отдельно от самого приложения, при его запуске. В таком случае вы где-то на внешнем сервере (хоть в GoogleDisk) будете просто менять файл бандла, а уже ваше приложение запустившись и получив последние данные будет скачивать только новый бандл. Т.е. приложение, по сути, превращается в подобие лаунчера для различных ммо-ПК игр

Подробнее об [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

Comment: проблема в том, что я обновляю приложение и при скачивание переустанавливается приложение полностью. 46 мб старый апк весил, новый 50. скачивает 50 мб, а не обновляет старую до новой.